# jQuery matching text in a menu and appending

Tags: jquery

I have the below jQuery that goes through each menu item and then matches the text inside the `a` tag with a `menuitem` through `ajax()`

What I'm trying to do is match the `data.name` with the `name` so that I can `append()` the `.main-menu ul li a .sub-menu` with the correct item from the `ajax()`

```
$('.main-menu > ul > li > a').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).text();
    name = name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.php",
        data: "name="+name,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if ($('.main-menu > ul > li > a:contains('+data.name+')').length > 0) {
                $(this).find('.sub-menu').append(data.menuitem);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.main-menu > ul > li > a').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).text();
    name = name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.php",
        data: "name="+name,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            name = data.name;
            name = name.replace('-', ' ');
            name = toTitleCase(name);
            $('.main-menu > ul > li > a').each(function(){
                if($(this).text() == name) {
                    $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').prepend(data.menuitem);
                }
            });
    }
    });
});
```